# Serial Execution faster than Parallel Execution with one thread of OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I am trying to compute value of pi using trapezoidal rule of numerical integration. For that I have written a serial code which does iterations in a given range. For computing the parallel overhead, I have run the same code by setting number of threads to 1. Now, I have obtained the following graph of execution time versus the problem size. 
Since, we are only creating one thread, I don't think there is much of communication overhead involved in this. So what might be the reason behind this? And as far as I know, the directive's invocation is done at compile time, i.e., if you define a MACRO then it gets expanded before runtime, so am I missing something there? Or is it something totally different from what I have thought?

Below is the serial code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("pi_serial.txt", "a+");
    long num_steps = 1e9;
    double step_size = 1.0 / num_steps;
    long i;
    double sum = 0;
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    for(i = 0; i< num_steps; i++) {
        double x = (i + 0.5) * step_size;
        sum += (4.0 / (1.0 + (x * x)));
    }
    sum = sum * step_size;
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    fprintf(fp, "%lf %lf\n", sum, end_time - start_time);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the multi-threaded code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("pi_parallel.txt", "a+");
    omp_set_num_threads(1);
    long num_steps = atol(argv[1]);
    double step_size = 1.0 / num_steps;
    double sum = 0;
    double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        double private_sum = 0;
        int i;
        for(i = id; i <= num_steps; i += 1){
            double x = (i + 0.5) * step_size;
            private_sum += (4.0 / (1.0 + x * x));
        }
        #pragma omp critical
            sum += private_sum;
    }
    sum *= step_size;
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    fprintf(fp, "%lf %lf\n", sum, end_time - start_time);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the graph for [Execution time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9zoo.png)

Comment: Critical section locking overheads?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya But there is only one thread. I don't think that would ever happen (Considering semaphore concept, semaphore was already initialized to 1 and the thread did not have to wait to update the result)

Comment: Serial and parallel code have the same runtime on my laptop.

Comment: Naive question: How is executing something with **one** thread *parallel*? I **guess** you just get the code for thread safety injected (which takes some time to execute, obviously).

Comment: It's entirely usual for the serial execution of an OpenMP program on one thread to be slower than the equivalent serial program.  The compiler may not be able to as aggressively optimise the parallel code as the serial code.  And then at run-time the code may pay a penalty in start-up performance of instantiating the OpenMP run time paraphernalia even though the code only uses one thread -- the run time doesn't know this in advance.

Comment: **Please clarify** 1) How did you ensure that only one thread was running during runtime? 2) What are your compiler versions and flags?

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuzYICZUthM&list=PLLX-Q6B8xqZ8n8bwjGdzBJ25X2utwnoEG&index=7

The above video will help in understanding why a serial code might be faster than a parallel code with one thread.
According to the presenter, it can be seen that since you are setting up omp environment variables, creating a thread in the middle of the program it is normal for the openmp program to run slower than the serial code.

But the main thing would be look at the scalability of your code- how fast is your code compared to serial when running on more than 1 thread?
When you are running the same code on multiple threads and still do not see an increase in performance it may be due to false sharing. From what I understand, consider two variables that reside in the same cache line. The master thread accesses one of the variables and modifies it which causes the cache line to be invalidated. If thread 1 has to access the modified cache line then the modified cache line is written to memory and the thread then fetches the cache line from memory and modifies it. This process may increase the execution time.

References:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37081/aewcy.html

*I dont own the video.

Comment: Link only answers are generally not useful over time. Can you expand on this answer, perhaps quoting relevant details from the link?